# Why does my Xbox keep signing me out of Xbox live

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

When ever I am playing Xbox it randomly signs me into Xbox live then later will sign me out of Xbox live and I don't know how to fix this little issue. If anyone knows the answer it would be much appreciated if you could help me out.

Comment: Are you talking about the Xbox 360? Are you perhaps connected via WiFi?

Comment: if your profile exists on another xbox somewhere, like a friend's house, make sure it's not signing in over there by mistake. Home Sharing can also produce this behavior when games do not share between consoles correctly

Answer (score 1):

if it is an xbox 360 it is usually a problem with your modem/network.

Restart your modem, if that doesn't work simply turn it off and play offline.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following steps:

- Do the Xbox live test (You can find it at the Network Settings);
- Re-download your profile;
- If your profile data is on a external drive, move it to the internal console HDD;
- If your console is not updated, accept any updates you have waiting.

If none of these steps fix your problem, try contacting Microsoft, your hardware may be faulty.